# Anchor link binding to different anchor

Tags: html, css

So I'm having a problem where some buttons in a seperate div are binding to a header I've absolute positioned the logo's and the intro section is a separate div.

Heres the html including buttons that aren't working

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo-right">
    <a href="http://thehedonistproject.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src="/img/project-logo.png" alt="Hedonist Project" /></a>
    <img src="/img/drinks-logo.png" alt="Hedonist Drinks" />
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="/img/logo.png" alt="Hedonist Events" /></a>
    <h4>a creative drinks consultancy</h4>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro__text editable"><h3>Hedonist Events are an events agency
    for bar staff, bar management, events production and pop-up bars.</h3>

    <div class="intro__buttons">
      <a class="btn" href="#contact">get in touch</a>
      <a class="btn" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="deck.html">see the event deck</a>
    </div>
```

Heres the css

```
.logo {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5.3em;
  left: 6.5em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  img {
    height: 3.5em;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
  }
  @media (max-width: 850px) {
    display: block;
    left: 4.3em;
  }
}

.logo-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5.3em;
  right: 12.5em;
  bottom: 0;
  img {
    height: 3.5em;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1300px) {
    right: 8em;
  }
  @media (max-width: 950px) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.header {
  height: 20em;
  width: 100%;
  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    height: 10em;
  }
}
```

Comment: your logo div seems to cover everything (apart from 6.5em to the left of the header) - that's probably your issue.  Also, you should position your header relatively.  But your question is unclear - you title states anchors binding to the wrong anchor and the your question says buttons binding to the header - very ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using absolute in this case the header as to be relative:. Also using absolute position and you want to align a tag left just use "left" no need for "right" unless you want it to fill the whole space of the relative container. Update your code with the below

```
.logo {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5.3em;
  left: 6.5em;
  img {
    height: 3.5em;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
  }
  @media (max-width: 850px) {
    display: block;
    left: 4.3em;
  }
}

.logo-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5.3em;
  right: 12.5em;
  img {
    height: 3.5em;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1300px) {
    right: 8em;
  }
  @media (max-width: 950px) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.header {
  height: 20em;
  width: 100%;
  position: relavtive;
  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    height: 10em;
  }
}
```